# How to check if firstrun has been skipped?

Tags: java, android

I have in my firstrun activity, a button that says "continue" and starts new activity (MainActivity intent), but I've found out it's possible skip that button and firstrun activity by restarting the app. So I would like to make sure it will be impossible to skip the activity.

That's what I have been thinking about:

firstEntry.java - In this method I'm putting new value in the shared preference that confirm that firstrun haven't been skipped (it only add the value if the button is clicked).

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean(skip, false);
editor.commit();
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
}
```

OnCreate() method in MainActivity

```
boolean skipper = prefs.getBoolean(skip, false);
        if(skipper == true){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), firstEntry.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

OnResume function:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {// Checks if application is on its first run
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), firstEntry.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

How can I check if shared preference method "firstrun" has skipped the continue button by using shared preference values?

Comment: I'm not very clear about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @ELITE preventing skipping the firstrun activity without clicking the continue button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change following line in btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

```
editor.putBoolean(skip, false);
```

to

```
editor.putBoolean(skip, true);
```

And then in OnCreate() method of firstEntry.java

```
boolean skipper = prefs.getBoolean(skip, false);
    if(skipper == true){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        Log.i("firstEntry.java","skipped the activity");
        startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: It's working though, you made a mistake and instead making skipper == false in the if and intent to the firstEntry, but I guess you misunderstood me.

Comment: but if you made skipper == false, firstEntry.java will never skipped

Comment: I wanna make sure it will never be skipped from mainactivity not from firstEntry